# Two rewrite rules in .htaccess files prevents me from accessing index file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my existing .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !^images

 RewriteRule ^files(.+)$ ../../fileManager/server/php/files/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ subpage.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'll try to explain this as best as I can without making it overly complicated. Ultimately, it boils down to this:

If a URL contains "/files" immediately after the root URL (ie: http://www.someurl.com/files/username/myFile.jpg), then it should direct the user to a specific URL (in this instance: ../../fileManager/server/php/files/$1).

With the second rule, if the URL contains anything other than "/files" after the root URL, it directs them to "subpage.php". (ie: http://www.someurl.com/aboutme)

Both of these work perfectly fine. However, with both of these rules in place, I can never get to / or /index.php (the root URL: http://www.someurl.com). I keep getting redirected to subpage.php.

But wait! There's more!

If I remove the first RewriteRule line:

```
 RewriteRule ^files(.+)$ ../../fileManager/server/php/files/$1 [L]
```

...then the second rewrite rule works as I want it to, in that if I go to / or /index.php, it takes me there, but if I go to any other URL, it directs me to subpage.php.

So what I don't understand is this: why is it that with both RewriteRules in there, I can't get to index.php, but with only the second RewriteRule in there, I can?

Additionally, can anybody give any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Any information would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RewriteConds only apply to the next RewriteRule. With both there, the RewriteConds only apply to the first one.

With only the second RewriteRule in there and the first removed, the test for index.php being a file prevents the rule applying.

With both there, the second rule applies to everything regardless of whether there is a file in place.

It looks like you want to repeat the RewriteConds for the second rule too.

Comment: As a follow-up question - my use of relative paths does not work when I upload the files to my server, though it works locally. If I change it to the full file path, it DOES work, however, the URL also changes - which I don't want. Is there any way for me to make my relative paths work after I upload?

Comment: Might be worth a separate question, but have a look at the [RewriteBase directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase).